# .htaccess file is not working correctly, should deny access to certain files, but it doesn't

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

For whatever unholy reason, the .htaccess file just doesn't work correctly.

My .htaccess file is just:

```
<Files .htaccess>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
<Directory ~ "\LAB3\backups">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Theoretically, it should deny all access to .htaccess and the directory "\LAB3\backups", [except it doesn't, and return 200 instead of 403.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go59M.png)

I suspect the problem might be the fact that I'm running it outside of the XAMPP folder.
My XAMPP installation folder is in C:/xampp, while the actual place I'm running the server is ~/tmp/phptmp, but idk.

Comment: This is Apache 2.2 syntax. Are you sure you are not running Apache 2.4? See https://htaccessbook.com/access-control-apache-2-4/ for changes from 2.2 to 2.4.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride All` set in your apache conf to enable .htaccess?  Can you introduce a syntax error in your .htaccess and make sure that there is then a "500 internal server error" caused by it?

Comment: The `<Directory>` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` - so this should be triggering a 500 error, if it is being processed at all. "I'm running it outside of the XAMPP folder" - that doesn't matter, but it needs to be a directory that is under the control of the web server (and `.htaccess` overrides enabled as mentioned above), so that maybe the problem. We would need to see your server config.

Comment: _Aside:_ "the actual place I'm running the server is `~/tmp/phptmp`" - In which case `"\LAB3\backups"` also looks incorrect? And you've declared this as a regex - is that really a regex?

Comment: @Enno yes, I was using Apache 2.4, I did not know that before posting the question. :p
@StephenOstermiller I have set `AllowOverride All`, though I haven't been able to cause a  `500` error.

Comment: @MrWhite the server is run in `~/tmp/phptmp` as in `C:/Users/<username>/tmp/phptmp`, the place I want to forbid access is `~/tmp/phptmp/LAB3/backups/`. Also it's not supposed to be regex, I was just copying anything I could find on the internet.